# Python-LDAP simple_bind_s timeout

Tags: python, timeout, python-ldap

Is there a way to set timeout for "simple_bind_s" in python-LDAP manually? I have tested ldapObject.timeout = 10 it did not work for me. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 16):

Set the option `ldap.OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT` for the ldap object.

```
import ldap

l = ldap.initialize('ldap://servername:389')
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 10.0)
l.simple_bind_s('username', 'password')
```

This will raise a ldap.SERVER_DOWN exception if the specified timeout is reached.

Answer (score 6):

For some reason `ldap.OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT` never seems to time out for me, so I used `ldap.OPT_TIMEOUT` instead (which will raise `ldap.TIMEOUT`):

```
import ldap

l = ldap.initialize('ldaps://ldap.example.com')
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_TIMEOUT, 10)
l.simple_bind_s('username', 'password')
```

Comment: I may be mistaken, but from what I can tell, the difference between OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT and OPT_TIMEOUT is that the "network" option is for the initial connection: fail to connect within 10 seconds, raise exception.  The OPT_TIMEOUT option seems to be for actions taken on the LDAP server: attempt to create a new record and it takes longer than 10 seconds, raise exception.